# Reveal NFT image/metadata after mint

Tags: nft, mint, meta-data

I would like to adapt my current contract to include a post mint image/metadata reveal feature. i.e. after an NFT is minted I would only then like the image/metadata to be revealed for that particular NFT.

Here is my sad attempt.

https://github.com/PALICADE/test/blob/main/exampleContract.sol

Any help or suggestions you can provide would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use tho different URIs. One for the pre-mint containing the general image and then changing that URI to the one containing the real images. From what I see you can already do it in your contract, just use the `changeBaseURI (string memory baseURI_) public onlyOwner` function when you want to do the revel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to do anything at all.

Your tokenURI function already starts with

```
 require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
```

If the token doesn't exist then the function will revert all by itself.

Comment: The problem with this is if all the files are already uploaded to IPFS, someone could snipe the rares once they know the base URI since most follow the format `baseURI/tokenID`, so once tokenID 1 is revealed and the URI format is known, you could see any tokens metadata. This article explains some solutions for that: https://medium.com/web-design-web-developer-magazine/how-generative-nft-reveals-work-options-and-strategies-for-a-smooth-secure-and-profitable-407390e509c8

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide a reveal on the blockchain because your transaction is public.
Here are the solutions I see:

- Make a centralised backend that does the reveal, with the baseURI pointing to the backend
- Host 'hidden' images with the baseURI leading to them and change the baseURI when needed at reveal